# In what cases is wa_id not a customer's phone number in WhatsApp webhook payload?

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

```
         "value": {
          "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
          "metadata": {
            "display_phone_number": "000000000",
            "phone_number_id": "00000000000000"
          },
          "contacts": [
            {
              "profile": {
                "name": "Test"
              },
              "wa_id": "300000000000"
            }
          ],
          "messages": [
            {
              "from": "300000000000",
              "id": "wamid.freferfrefrefrefrefregfrefrefrefer",
              "timestamp": "1695917563",
              "text": {
                "body": "Test"
              },
              "type": "text"
            }
          ]
        },
```

It is stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/components/) that wa_id ('wa_id' and 'from' fields in the payload above) may not always match the customer's phone number. From this, there are two questions:

1. What else can be there besides a phone number and in what cases? On the test account, I always receive only the phone number.
2. If something other than a phone number (such as an alphanumeric identifier) can be there, is it possible to obtain the real phone number based on it?

Comment: Can you describe where you want to use `wa_id` so would suggest an alternative way? otherwise, you have to ask the meta developer team about your questions.